# how to upload folder in asp.net with c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

how to upload folder in asp.net with c# code

I need to select a folder in web application then need to retrieve all the files name in that folder

how to select a folder to upload in c#

Comment: u want to get a folder by httpFILEcollection? you see my point?

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Are you wanting to select a folder on your server to save the files to?

Comment: i need to select folder in asp.net using html input file

Comment: What do you mean _select a folder_?

Comment: i have some files in a folder i need to select that folder and need to show that file name in a gridview in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the filename use uploadedFiles.GetKey(i); returns filename as string

Comment: i have some files in a folder i need to select that folder and need to show that file name in a gridview in asp.net

Comment: HttpFileCollection only allows you to access the files that the user has uploaded. You cannot access the files on the clients PC via a web app as that would cause all sorts of security issues.